# SSL on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have done almost all the steps to get SSL on Elastic Beanstalk, but I am stuck for the last step.

What I did:

1) Get a domain name on GoDaddy -> that works

2) Redirect the DNS with Route53 (using A, Aliast - target being my EB environment) -> that works

Then:

3) Generate an SSL certificate with AWS Certificate Manager for example.com and *.example.com  -> that works

4) Go to my EB environment and change the protocol to HTTPS as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html

Problem: the 'Network Tier' panel is not displayed on my console (see screenshot):
[Image Network tier missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvCZI.png)

What am I missing? Why I cannot see the Network Tier? Is that the way to make example.com accessible through HTTPS (knowing that example.com points to my EB load balancer)?

Note: my application runs with nginx + Node.js. The nginx configuration file is in my .ebextensions folder

Comment: Is your EB environment a single instance environment or a load balanced environment? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html

Comment: Environment type: Load balanced, auto scaling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an alternative solution, although I still don't know why I can't see the 'Network Tier' panel.

Got on EC2 -> Load Balancing -> Load Balancers
Click on the load balancer corresponding to your Elastic Beanstalk environment, go to the 'Listeners' tab -> "Add listener" -> Choose HTTPS then follow the instructions on screen.

I hope it helps!

Nb: if you have any idea for the 'Network tier' panel unavailable, I'd be happy to hear from you!

Comment: It seems like a bug

Comment: It may have something to do with the choice between Classic and Application load balancers

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Which region did you use? I cannot see the Network Tier either and I am using sa-east-1.

Comment: Also, the security group might need to be updated to allow for inbound HTTPS.

Comment: I was using EU (Ireland), but I don't think the region matters. It's about the load balancer you choose when creating the Elastic Beanstalk. In order to see the Network Tier panel, you need the Classic Load Balancer. Glad it helped you @nbeuchat :-)

Comment: Great, thanks for the information. That will be helpful to know when creating my next EB :-)

Comment: How would you configure if you also had some static hosting on GoDaddy?

Comment: You'd probably need to use subdomains, and add HTTPS to the subdomains only.